# Not able to log into salesforce developer org,Had enabled authenticator but accidently removed my salesforce account from it

Tags: authentication, login, two-factor-authentication

I am not able to log into salesforce developer org, I enabled authenticator but accidentally removed my salesforce account from it .Now when I try to log in it asks to reconnect the account but on authenticator app does not have any option to do that, what do I do?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.disconnect_salesforce_authenticator_v2_or_later.htm&type=5     - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_authenticator_remove_account.htm&type=5

Comment: That won't help, to do both of those actions you need to have access to the org, currently, the user does not have access because of MFA

Comment: In the org, does any other admin user exist or not?

Comment: Do you have any other admin users or users with the Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in User Interface permission who login into the org? If yes then ask them to disconnect MFA from your user detail page as mentioned in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.disconnect_salesforce_authenticator_v2_or_later.htm&type=5) article.

Comment: Unfortunately, no there is no other user who can log into org and disconnect MFA , In that case i guess i lost my org permanently.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a partner, you may be able to engage partner support to recover this org. Otherwise, if you're already using the Salesforce CLI, you can use `sf org open -o username-or-alias` open an active session to disconnect or reset the authenticator. If neither of this options apply, you've probably lost your org permanently, as technical support can only fix certain problems if you're a partner or high-ranking official of an actual organization.